# Minted Assembly code indentation problems

Tags: alignment, minted, programming

I want to align the code as in the source code (image 1), because as you can see in the output (image 2) it comes out completely different.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

% Language setting
% Replace `english' with e.g. `spanish' to change the document language
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

% Set page size and margins
% Replace `letterpaper' with `a4paper' for UK/EU standard size
\usepackage[a4paper,top=0.2cm,bottom=0.5cm,left=1cm,right=0.5cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\begin{document}


LPS23-AP3 exercise 1.1

% attributi eliminati: frame=single,
% nasm -> MIPS32 oppure gas
\begin{minted}[linenos,framesep=20pt,tabsize=4, autogobble, breaklines]{gas}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: It seems you use tabulators in the code that are translated to 4 spaces by minted. You could try it with spaces.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't depend on tabsize

Comment: You'll have more success when you provide code that can be copied as a whole and pasted into a TeX system, i. e. an MWE. People are lazy and it is your responsibility as the asker to circumvent our laziness by making it as cozy as possible. Make sure your MWE produces the error you are talking about. This process might already solve your problem. If so, please report back (or delete the whole thing if it isn't useful to anyone anymore, which is very rare, btw). ;)